# how can i preview the name of the image at the bottom and whenever i upload an image it will create in new div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can i preview the name of the image at the bottom and whenever i upload an image it will create in new div.please help if any one can do this.....

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>






<div class="card">
<img id="blah" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />
//at the bottom of the image the image name will appear not beside the choose file 
</div>


<input type="file" 
    onchange="document.getElementById('blah').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
```

Comment: What will be created in the new div? Image, or image name? And what do you mean by the name of the image? alt?

Comment: @ sergey kuznetsov whenever i upload image create a new card  and show the next image. like multiples images with multiple cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function EmbbedImg(currentElement)
{
  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.class="card";
  var imgs = document.createElement("img");
  imgs.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(currentElement.files[0]);
  card.appendChild(imgs); 
  var spans = document.createElement("span");
  spans.innerHTML="<br>"+currentElement.files[0].name;
  card.appendChild(spans); 
  document.getElementById("allCard").appendChild(card);
  currentElement.value='';
}
```

```html
<div id="allCard">

</div>

<input type="file" onchange="EmbbedImg(this);">
```

Comment: how can i upload multiple images in multiple cards.whenever i choose a new image create a new card and show the new image . can you please do this.......

Comment: @Aisha , You can run same code now... it will appear multiple on multiple file upload and in different card class...

Comment: @Aisha , :) Now i removed unwanted line and update above.. you can check that too..

Comment: @Aisha , Yeah sure...:)

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the name of the uploaded file and insert it into a new container.
Your attempt with `this.files[0]` is not wrong. You just had to append a `.name` to get the name and assign this value to a new container.

```js
function selectedNewFile(myFile){
  document.getElementById('blah').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(myFile)
  document.getElementById('filename').textContent = myFile.name
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="card">
<img id="blah" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />
<span id="filename">No file selected</span>
</div>

<input type="file" 
    onchange="selectedNewFile(this.files[0])">
```

Comment: how can i upload multiple images in multiple cards.whenever i choose a new image create a new card and show the new image . can you please do this.......